# Trying to sync stock variations

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

For some reason when I import a new CSV to sync my stock feed using WP all import, my products that have variations go down to 1 colour and 1 size. I'm using _sku to match the stock level. Importing the origin CSV works fine, all the stock levels, variations all work wonderful, it's just when I update the stock levels.

I have followed the WP all Import tutorial which shows exactly what do to http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/woocommerce/syncing-stock/ however, this is for simple product. When I do what it states it just gives me the same problem of 1 colour and 1 size, even though on the documentation it does say this works for variations, but it's not.

What i'm also confused about is there are 2 inventory tabs, 1 for general inventory and one in the variations tab.

I unfortunately don't have any code which I apologise but I was hoping someone might of had the same problem. I have looked absolutely everywhere including under my bed but I just can't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: try this links please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162644/wp-all-import-stock-ovewritte https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313782/wp-all-import-update-stock-quantity-from-multiple-xml-files/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ,for me this method was useful:

1. give the unique SKU for each your variantions
2. check the updating conditions (and conndotions of variations in wp all importer steps )

Try this changes.